# Vanishing of a covector (1-form) and a vector field

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds

a) A one-form $\theta$ is zero if and only if $\theta X = 0$ for all $X$ in the set $\frak{X} \mathrm{(M)}$ of all smooth vector fields on a manifold $M$.

b) A vector field $X$ is zero if and only if $\theta X = 0$ for all $\theta \in \frak{X} ^* \mathrm{(M)}$.

a) Let $\theta \in \frak{X}^* \mathrm{(M)}$ and $X \in \frak{X} \mathrm{(M)}$.
(i) Assume $\theta = 0$. Let $\theta$ act on any $X$. Then $\theta X = (0)X = 0$. (ii) Assume $\theta X = 0$ for all $X$. Since the equality holds for all $X$, then $\theta$ must be zero.

b) Let $\theta \in \frak{X}^* \mathrm{(M)}$ and $X \in \frak{X} \mathrm{(M)}$. (i) Assume $X = 0$. Let any $\theta$ act on $X$. Then $\theta X = \theta (0) = 0$. (ii) Assume $\theta X = 0$ for all $\theta$. Since the equality holds for all $\theta$, then $X$ must be zero.

Are my proofs sufficient for the two statements, or am I still missing something? Thanks!

Comment: for the second you have to use a basis for the vector fields and the one form locally.

Comment: What's wrong (or what fails) with the second proof and why the need for the bases?

Comment: because you simply restated your proposition.

Answer (score 0):

For the non-trivial part of $a)$ you have to proof that 
$$
\theta_p V = 0 
$$
for every $V \in T_p M$ and therefore you must show that there is a smooth vector field $X$ such that $X|_p=V$. Hint: bump function.

For the non-trivial part of $b)$ the assumption is
$$
\theta X = 0 
$$
for all $\theta$ and you want to show that $X|_p=0$. This is true if
$$
\alpha X|_p=0
$$
for all $\alpha \in T_p^* M$. Is there a $\theta$ such that $\theta_p = \alpha$ for any $\alpha \in T_p^* M$?